# How to change order of ContentBlock render in draftjs?

Tags: draftjs, draft-js-plugins

Got an question about draft js.

How i can change an order of ContentBlocks?
Im trying to add an external link to content and render video inside of Editor.

Creating current state:

```
createEditorState(source) {
        if (!source) {
          return EditorState.createEmpty();
        }

        const contentState = stateFromMarkdown(source);
        const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);

        return addVideoContent(source, editorState)
 }
```

Add block with video content (supported to be rendered via video-plugin):

```
addVideoContent(source, editorState) {
    function buildNewEditorState(state, src) {
      const currentContentState = state.getCurrentContent();
      const contentStateWithEntity = currentContentState
        .createEntity(VIDEO_PLUGIN_TYPE, 'IMMUTABLE', { src });
      const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();

      return AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(state, entityKey, ' ');
    }

    //defining video urls
    ...

    return videoUrls.reduce(buildNewEditorState, editorState);
}
```

Problem is in render order: 1. Video block; 2. Link block.

How to change this order to: 1. Link block; 2. Video block.

Comment: that's depends on how you render your atomic block. please show more codes

Comment: render of atomic block is handled via draft-js-video-plugin. I found `AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock` modify my contentState in next way: right before calling method, contentState had one block on index 0 - `{key: "dkdl8", text: "https://....", type: "unstyled"}`, after calling - 3 blocks: 0 - empty block `{key: "eih8o", text: "", type: "unstyled"}` 1 - atomic block `{key: "4694p", text: " ", type: "atomic"}` 2 - original block `{key: "dkdl8", text: "https://...", type: "unstyled"}`. So problem is `AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock` changing order of blocks.

Comment: so just make your own video-plugin and change the block order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. issue was in selectionState.

When initial state initialized, selectionState (position of anchor and focus) is equals to first character of first block. So `AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock` method will split blocks between selectionState and insert 'atomic'.

Decision: `EditorsState.moveSelectionToEnd(editorState)`.